# Rails has_many/belongs_to on custom database ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch got Fixnum

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have the database from another non-rails project so I have to deal with unordinary column names. I have the model Category:

```
self.primary_key = "categoryID"
has_many :products, foreign_key: "category", primary_key: "categoryID"
```

And the model Product:

```
self.primary_key = "productID"
belongs_to :category, foreign_key: "category", primary_key: "categoryID"
```

In the `Product`'s table there's a foreign key `category` which stores a primary key of `Category`'s table, which is `categoryID`. I'm trying to create a product in a console like that:

```
c = Category.last
p = c.products.create
```

And I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Category(#29703600) expected, got Fixnum(#17843240)
```

I tried some other ways to create a product where I could pass the Category instance there but it leads to other weird errors. So now I just want this way to work. 
Where is a problem?

Comment: and just `c.products` works?

Comment: Yes it works. But I had to create a product from seeds and even there it doesn't accept an integer for the category field, it only accepts category instance
    Product.create({category: c})

Comment: I think it's because you have DB column `category` and association with the same name.

Comment: I agree with the comment about how you have a column and an association with the same name 'category' and so their is a naming collision. Have you inherited a db? Why are you not following standard naming conventions for columns?

Comment: Because this project has to use the DB which is used for a non-rails project, so it has different name conventions and I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have `category` column (so Rails creates `category` method for it) and `category` association with the same name.
You can give some another name to association

I created test app

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :productID
      t.integer :category
      t.string  :title
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :categoryID
      t.string  :title
    end
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :productID

  belongs_to :my_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :categoryID

  has_many :products, foreign_key: :category
end
```

This way the following code seems to work fine

```
c = Category.create categoryID: 1, title: 'First category'
c.products # => []
c.products.create productID: 1, title: 'First product' 
c.products.create productID: 2, title: 'Second product'
c.products # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product productID: 1, category: 1, title: "First product">, #<Product productID: 2, category: 1, title: "Second product">]>

p = Product.first
p.category # => 1
p.my_category # => #<Category categoryID: 1, title: "First category">
```

Comment: not at all, but it is a matter of honor to make a comment to those guys with so strange column names =)

Comment: Those guys no longer work there. Anyway their website was made with php and wordpress, so I don't think a column names like these are strange for them